# Using React, how can I update state from inside a custom function?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

I'm trying to use React Hooks with the Google Places API to autocomplete a location search, find the Google Place ID for the location and then update my component state with the value.

I have the Google API working and I am able to get the Place ID, but I'm not sure how to update my state from the function I am.

```
function onMapsLoad() {
  // init autocomplete
  const autocomplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementsByClassName('search')[0]);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    // define place and place ID
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    const placeID = place.place_id;

    // how can I update the component state from inside this function?
  });
}

function myComponent() {
  const [placeID, setPlaceID] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement(`script`);
    const headScript = document.getElementsByTagName(`script`)[0];

    script.type = `text/javascript`;
    script.src = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}&libraries=places`;

    script.addEventListener('load', onMapsLoad);
  });
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move the function inside the component (thus making setPlaceID be in scope):

```
function myComponent() {
  const [placeID, setPlaceID] = useState(null);

  function onMapsLoad() {
    // ... same as before, but then ending with a call to:
    setPlaceID(placeID);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Or pass setPlaceID in as a parameter

```
function onMapsLoad(setPlaceID) {
    // ... 
    setPlaceID(placeID);
}

function myComponent() {
  const [placeID, setPlaceID] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // ... same as before, except the last line:
    script.addEventListener('load', () => onMapsLoad(setPlaceID));
  });
}
```

Comment: Of course that seems so obvious now that I see it. Thank you very much! Can you think of any advantages or disadvantages to either approach?

Comment: I usually recommend the first option. It creates a new function each time your component renders, which means the values in its closure are always up to date with the component. It does mean a new function is created every render. The time to create a function is trivial (on the order of nanoseconds), so don't worry about that aspect. But if you're passing this function down to a child component, a changing function can break the child's shouldComponentUpdate. If that occurs, you can use useMemo or useCallback. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback